# Using boolean indexing or groupby to sum customers and identify products

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

In my dataset I found that disloyal 30-40 year old customers were dissatisfied with Company X. I want to find out the sums of the customers' responses.

In other words, how many `Dissatisfied` `Disloyal` `30-40` year old customers ranked Product A between 0-2 and Product B between 0-2 out of a possible rating of 5.

```
Customer Cat    Age    Satisfaction    Prod A Rank   Prod B Rank  Gender    House Style    Distance
    Disloyal     28    Dissatisfied              1           2
       Loyal     30       Satisfied              3           5
    Disloyal     36    Dissatisfied              0           2
```

Finally, what products did these customers rank <=2?

Comment: Please, post you progress so far and tell us what is going wrong.

Comment: Nothing is going wrong. I'm simply unable to group what I need to group because of the complexity.

Comment: Doesn't sound very complex. The general idea is: `len([x for x in data if x['ARank'] >= 2 and x[`BRank'] >= 2])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do everything with [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html):

```
sub = df[
    (df["Customer Cat"] == "Disloyal")
    & (df["Satisfaction"] == "Dissatisfied")
    & df["Age"].between(30, 40)
]
```

Then you run your analysis like:

```
sub[(sub["Prod A Rank"] <= 2) & (sub["Prod B Rank"] <= 2)].shape[0]
# Given your example this outputs 1
```

Alternatively, if you want to know whether your subset of customer was dissatisfied with either one of your products you can use the logical operator `|` (OR):

```
sub[(sub["Prod A Rank"] <= 2) | (sub["Prod B Rank"] <= 2)].shape[0]
```

If you want to study the products, you can try this:

```
(sub.melt(value_vars=[c for c in sub.columns if c.startswith("Prod")])
    .groupby("variable")
    .value_counts()
    .to_frame()
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={0: "count"}))
```

This outputs:

```
    variable    value   count
0   Prod A Rank 0       1
1   Prod B Rank 2       1
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Works very nicely. Since I now know those customer totals, how can I find out what those products were? I iterated through 30 product columns using a hard coded list and for loop because only some of the columns contain survey ratings. I know I'm dealing with (columns) + column series objects (column values).

Comment: Check out my new edit, see if that works for you

Comment: So nice man. Thanks a lot. I noticed you used `"Prod"` because my question has only 2 products. I created a series object from iterating a list of 30 column names and called it `product_columns`. If I want to use that instead can I do something like `sub.columns if c.isin(df[product_columns])`?

Comment: if `product_columns` is a Series object with the names of the columns you need, you can turn it into a list with `product_columns.tolist()` and then you can pass that to `value_vars`

Comment: I will post a new question. Your code is perfect but my logic is incorrect and I have to post using my actual dataset which is more complex.  If you keep an eye out for it and answer it I can mark it correct.

Answer (score -1):

IIUC, you can try

```py
count = (df['Age'].isin(range(30,41)) & df['Prod A Rank'].isin([0,1,2]) & df['Prod B Rank'].isin([0,1,2])).sum()
# or
count = (df['Age'].between(30,40) & df['Prod A Rank'].between(0,2) & df['Prod B Rank'].between(0,2)).sum()
```

Comment: @Edison Simply add the `age` constraint.

Comment: @Edison Maybe you can write a dict that stores product and constraint and loop the condition.

Comment: Still no categorical columns.